# Translating Stata Loop

Tags: r, loops, stata, translate

I'd like to translate the following Stata loop to R:

```
foreach day of numlist 1/7 {;
replace dywt = 1/7 * 1/Freq[`day',1] if interview_day==`day';
}
```

Data (R Output):

```
> INTERVIEW_DAY[1:15]
 [1] 5 6 6 4 4 4 1 2 6 4 6 7 6 3 6

> Freq
[1] 0.14353969 0.14795762 0.14089618 0.14074198 0.14194271 0.14295769 0.14196413

> F
[1] 20720

> DYWT[1:15]
 [1] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you  show the input data.  I guess it is the output you wanted?

Comment: You would be more likely to get an answer if you explain what you want to achieve in `R` with an example data, regardless how `Stata` does it.

Comment: Hi @akrun! The old history of the frequency table... now it's the weighting of the "days of the week" in Stata. I guess this line with the loop is self-executing, it's not related to any variable, except to those used for the math operations. Ty.

Comment: I am guessing you need `DYWT <- 1/INTERVIEW_DAY * 1/Freq[INTERVIEW_DAY]`

Comment: @akron could you please explain what is meant with the interval '[`day',1]? Ty.

Comment: @Econ_Spectre  Issue is also that most of us do not have `stata` or use `stata`.  So, if the expected is not shown, it is a bit of guess work

Comment: @Econ_Spectre  Based on the stata code, I am guessing that it is looping over each of the 'numlist' 1 to 7 and extracting the corresponding position value of 'Freq' which is vectorized in R based on a check with the value of  INTERVIEW_DAY

Comment: @Econ_Spectre  I don't see `F` (`20720`) being used in the stat code

Comment: @akrun. the [Freq] is found at the second line of the loop in the question.
Did I understand it right: Freq is just an object with 7 columns, 1 row. R can retrieve the position of the element which composes a certain frequency displayed in "Freq"? Everytime I create an object in R like this, is saves all elements that led to that number? Ty.

Comment: @Econ_Spectre  From what you showed, `Freq` is just a vector.  `Freq[INTERVIEW_DAY]` expands the `Freq` values to the same length as INTERVIEW_DAY based on the position index of INTERVIEW_DAY and do the mltiplication

Comment: @akrun, ty for the detailed explanation, it is helping me a lot. Forgive my stupid question, but what do you exactly mean with "@Econ_Spectre From what you showed, Freq is just a vector. Freq[INTERVIEW_DAY] expands the Freq values to the same length as INTERVIEW_DAY"?

Comment: @Econ_Spectre  I meant this `v1 <- c(0.5, 0.3, 0.1); ind <- c(3, 2, 1, 1, 3, 2, 3); v1[ind]`  If you check the values of `v1[ind]` the values of original vector is getting filled for each position given by 'ind'

Comment: FWIW, no loop was or is needed in Stata. The calculation is just `replace dywt = 1/7 * 1/Freq[interview_day,1]`

Comment: Hi @Nick Cox, the code wasn't designed by me. It is available on Internet to reproduce the article Aguiar et al. (AER, 2013). Aguiar uses replace throughout the code, but for this specific case, he used the Stata function "foreach", which is indeed a loop in Stata, according to it own help files (" [P] foreach -- Loop over items). Ty for your time anyway

Comment: Ok, but (1) we don't know what you don't tell us (2) "on Internet" is not a precise reference (3) regardless of (1) and (2) readers of this -- including R people -- could well be interested. In my experience economists often err in assuming that everyone else is an economist and can decode their cryptic literature references.

Comment: `foreach` is a Stata command, not a function. I was aware of what `foreach` does, but no harm in spelling it out.  Naturally it **is** a loop command, but as said you don't need it.

Comment: @Nick Cox, thanks for you reply. As you may have noticed, I'm a complete beginner in programming, even using the terminology... "command", "function". I know it's a huge difference, but I'll try to pay more attention to that. Regarding the reference, I'm in kinda dilemma... some want really detailed info, others as summarized as possible. You spelling that out helped me a lot, now I know I don't need loops in Stata, I didn't know that. If I may ask one more think is: how to format commands in the comment, so they appear like you did for "foreach"? Thank you again and have a good day

Comment: Use paired single backticks. \`  is the symbol.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `R`, if all of them are `vector`s, then the equivalent would be to just replace the `NA`  vector ('DYWT') by getting corresponding 'Freq' for each sequence value of 'INTERVIEW_DAY' (`Freq[INTERVIEW_DAY]` - as `INTERVIEW_DAY` is a sequence of numeric vector which can be used as position vector for 'Freq'), divide by 1, and multiply with `1/max(INTERVIEW_DAY)`

```
DYWT <- 1/max(INTERVIEW_DAY) * 1/Freq[INTERVIEW_DAY]
```

Or if it is based on the number of unique elements, it can be also

```
DYWT <- 1/length(unique(INTERVIEW_DAY)) * 1/Freq[INTERVIEW_DAY]
```

or it is `1/7` where `7` is the number of unique elements in 'INTERVIEW_DAY' (if some of the index are missing, then it may be better to use `1/7`)

#### data

```
INTERVIEW_DAY <- scan(text = '5 6 6 4 4 4 1 2 6 4 6 7 6 3 6', what = integer())
Freq <- scan(text = '0.14353969 0.14795762 0.14089618 0.14074198 0.14194271 0.14295769 0.14196413', what = numeric())
```

Comment: just a little corretion to your code, which worked nicely: it's DYWT <-  1/7 * 1/Freq[INTERVIEW_DAY]

Comment: @Econ_Spectre Here `1/max(INTERVIEW_DAY)` is same as `1/7` or `1/length(unique(INTERVIEW_DAY))`

Comment: my I ask you something? How can I quote the total number of observations in a command line/function? I'm asking because I will use some codes on more than one dataset, and the different datasets have different number of observations. So, I would like not to have to change this number everytime, for ex. the number 20720:

timeuse_2003$N_WEIGHT <- timeuse_2003$WEIGHT * 20720/ sum(timeuse_2003$WEIGHT)

Comment: @Econ_Spectre If you are creating a function, then you can pass the number as an argument.  And if you want something with commandlne, perhaps check `?commandArgs`